# What is the difference between Logical connection and User connections?

Tags: sql-server

I have a simple question.

What is the difference between Logical connection and User connection in MS SQL server ?

I am using perfmon to get SQL connection count. In that I found two options, Logical connection and User connection. But no where I am getting the exact differences between these.

So please help me.

Answer (score 3):

I looked into the [Books Online Do](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190697.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)c, it says

> Number of logical connections to the system.
>
> The main purpose of logical connections is to service [multiple active
>   result sets (MARS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131686.aspx) requests. For MARS requests, every time that an
>   application makes a connection to SQL Server, there may be more than
>   one logical connection that corresponds to a physical connection.
>
> When MARS is not used, the ratio between physical and logical
>   connections is 1:1. Therefore, every time that an application makes a
>   connection to SQL Server, logical connections will increase by 1.

Comment: That comparison is between Logical and Physical connection. Whether user connection and physical connections are same ? Also I didnt understand meaning of Logical connection from that definition and that is why I asked in this forum. Can you please explain with an example if you understood that definition.

Comment: The whole difference relies on whether you understand MARS, do you ?. What it is saying is with MARS being active the same physical connection or user connection can open new logical connection. Basically it allows applications to have more than one pending request per connection, and in particular, to have more than one active default result set per connection. I suggest you read MARS definition from BOL.